# IE11.0.26 Unsupported Error for mergeAttributes

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, datatables

I am a web development contractor working at a government agency.  We have just begun to experience issues with our pages and I believe it has to do with Internet Explorer 11.0.26 and jQuery DataTable.  We are using jQuery v1.7 and DataTables 1.9, I know they are old but they did work with IE 11.0.25.

The javaScript (JS) fails with an “Unsupported Error” on the “mergeAttributes” method.  This I believe is still included in the IE11 browser API.

Does anyone know what would cause this error and under what conditions?

Thanks for you assistance.

Comment: A JSFiddle would be really useful in order to illustrate your use case.

Comment: I have been working on this but the code I create, ultimately works.  The original HTML is created by JSP and I copied the resulting HTML and the results were different.  I'll see if I can get an example to fail this weekend

Comment: Okay, let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:** I`ve found and source of this issue and created new question as i need some assistance to deal with it, here is my question with explanations: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946941/ie11-bug-calling-javascript-getattributenode-method-brakes-mergeattributes)

I managed to recreate it, so in my case  mergeAttributes method is screwed up after some special css selector is used (i`ve been using mootols in my case). in IE 11 (11.0.27) with IE=7 rendering mode.

My guess: jQuery/Mootools selectors in some cases modifies Elements attribute list.

Here is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools.js"></script>
<style type='text/css'>
.ORG{
  width: 400px;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.addEvent('domready',function(){
   $('btn').addEvent('click',function(){
    $$('.randomClass') //<--WORKS
    $('cln').mergeAttributes($('inp'))
  })

    $('btnS').addEvent('click',function(){
      $$('input[class=randomClass]') // Screw ups mergeAttributes method.
    try{$('cln').mergeAttributes($('inp'))}catch(e){
      alert(e.description)
    }
  })
})
</script>


<input type='text' id='inp' value="ORIGINAL" class='ORG'></input><br>
<input type='text' id='cln' value="CLONE" class='none'></input><br>
<input type='button' value='Merrge Classes' id='btn'></input><br>
<input type='button' value='Merrge Classes, but before initiat Class selector' id='btnS'></input> <-- Seceltor used '$$('input[class=randomClass]')'
```

Demo (was not able to use jsfiddle as this bug appear **only in IE=7** rendering mode): 
[Here is demo](http://geltonas.info/clone.html)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I am not sure we found the exact cause but it was in the _fnDraw function (this might not be the exact function name) but the tHead clone was/is not function correctly.  In our application if we removed the sScrollX/Y from the table definition the error did not occur.  The down side was the fixed column headers were no longer on the tables.  We also tried changing the .clone with .cloneNode which fixed the tables and allowed the sScrollX/Y to be specified.  Another problem arose and the table sorting ceased to function.  cloneNode does not copy the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the FIX for this issue.  It was provided by carranthuohill3 on the dataTable forum and refferenced Dottoro.com

```
   // mergeAttributes, in contrast, only merges back on the
   // original attributes, not the events
    try{
        if ( dest.mergeAttributes ) {
            dest.mergeAttributes( src );
        }
    } catch (exception) {
        for (var i=0; i < src.attributes.length; i++) {
            var attr = src.attributes[i];
            var attrName = attr.name.toLowerCase ();
            if (attrName != "id" && attrName != "name") {
                dest.setAttribute (attr.name, attr.value);
            }
        }
    }
```